# Insert data into two columns only if not duplicate

Tags: sql, insert, duplicates

I have a table user_interests with id(AUTO_INC), user_id, user_interest columns.
I want a easy way to insert data into user_id and user_interest without duplicate entries.

E.g. if I have a table like this before.

```
+------------------------------+
| ID | user_id | user_interest |
+------------------------------+
| 1  | 2       | Music         |
| 2  | 2       | Swimming      |
+------------------------------+
```

If I now `insert into table (user_id, user_interest) values ((2, Dance),(2, Swimming)`, I only need (2,dance) entry to be inserted - not (2, swimming) since (2, swimming) already exists in the table.

I have seen `upsert` commands, and have also tried creating a command like below but it doesn't work.

```
INSERT INTO `user_interests`( `user_id`,`interest` )
VALUES ("2","Music")
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(`interest`) FROM `user_interests`
       WHERE `interest` = "Music" AND `user_id` = "2"
       Having COUNT(`interest`) <=0 )
```

Comment: Add a unique constraint to the table, i.e. `unique(user_id, user_interest)`.

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. Add some more sample data - and attempted insert data - and show us the expected result!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use NOT EXISTS method :

```
INSERT INTO your_table (user_id ,user_interest )
SELECT @userId , @UserIntreset 
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM your_table user_id = @userid AND user_interest 
= @userinterest )
```

Or Create unique constraint in your table,

```
 ALTER TABLE your_table 
 ADD CONSTRAINT Constraint_Name UNIQUE (Column_Name1,Column_Name2)
```